# Delete duplicates in an array but add a count property to see the number of duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates

Basically if I had this array:

```
[{"id" = 1, "product" = "Book"}, {"id" = 1, "product" = "Book"}, {"id" = 1, "product" = "Book"}, {"id" = 2, "product" = "Chair"}]
```

It would turn into this array:

```
 [{"id" = 1, "product" = "Book", "count" = 3}, {"id" = 2, "product" = "Chair", "count" = 1}]
```

I am using react. Another option I have is to add the count property when making and adding to the array so that duplicates don't get added, but I am curious if there is a way to do it with an existing array.

Edit:
If two products have the same id they are duplicates.

I have tried filtering the array by using the id, then getting the first object. I filtered the array again by id to get the length. Then I added a new property "count" to the first object which is the length of the filtered array, after that I added the first object to a new array.
The problem with doing it this way is that I have to hard code this for every possible id even if it is not included in my array.

Comment: What have you tried already? What counts as a duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @DrewReese Edited my post with answers to your question.

Comment: FYI, JavaScript object key / values are defined like `key: value`, **not** `key = value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reduce the array to a `Map` (or even just a plain object) keyed by `id` (assuming that's all it takes to identify a duplicate).

The values of that map will be the array you're after.

```js
const arr = [{"id":1,"product":"Book"},{"id":1,"product":"Book"},{"id":1,"product":"Book"},{"id":2,"product":"Chair"}]

const zipped = Array.from(arr.reduce((map, o) => {
  // check if id already registered
  if (map.has(o.id)) {
    // increment count
    map.get(o.id).count++
  } else {
    // otherwise, store the new object with count starting at 1
    map.set(o.id, { ...o, count: 1 })
  }
  return map
}, new Map()).values())

console.log(zipped)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height:100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce the array into a new array with the `count` property added. The `id` property is assumed to be sufficient for considering uniqueness. If the element has already been seen then increment the `count`, otherwise append a new augmented element object.

```js
const data = [{
  "id": 1,
  "product": "Book"
}, {
  "id": 1,
  "product": "Book"
}, {
  "id": 1,
  "product": "Book"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "product": "Chair"
}];

const dedupedData = data.reduce((data, el) => {
  const index = data.findIndex(item => item.id === el.id);
  if (index !== -1) {
    data[index].count++;
  } else {
    data.push({ ...el, count: 1 });
  }
  return data;
}, []);

console.log(dedupedData);
```